# Value of type 'Array<Any>?' has no member 'removeAtIndex'

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I tried to use **removeAtIndex** function to delete item from my array, but when I run the code I get an error that "Value of type 'Array?' has no member 'removeAtIndex'".
Maybe somebody had the same problem and can help me to solve it, here is my code:

```
var cards:Array<Any>?
let i : Int = (sender.layer.value(forKey: "index")) as! Int
    cards.removeAtIndex(i)
```

Thank You!

Comment: In Swift 3+ it's `cards.remove(at: i)`

Comment: @vadian thanks, for helping, but when I run it - I got similar error "Value of type 'Array<Any>?' has no member 'remove'"

Comment: You have to unwrap or option chain `cards`: `cards!.remove(at: i)` or `cards?.remove(at: i)`. Why is the array optional at all? And why is it `Any`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var arr = Array<Any>()
 arr = ["1","2","3"]
 arr.remove(at: 2)
 print(arr) // It prints ["1","2"]
```

In Array, we don't have removeAtIndex() . Use remove(at: Int)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

```
 var cards:Array<Any>? = []
 let i : Int = (sender.layer.value(forKey: "index")) as! Int
 cards?.remove(at: i)
```

Comment: Hey @Dan Did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: So would a construction like `links.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)`, for example, become `links.remove(at: indexPath.row)`?